# Magento 2 Mass Product Action module (append text to products name , update price....)

Tags: product, magento-2.1, uicomponent, massaction, uielement

I need the code of the module magento 2 which allows to add mass action  (append text to products name , update price....) I am blocked help me
please
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you are looking for the "attributes" massaction defined in 
`Magento_Catalog::view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml` within the Magento_Catalog module, right?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    ...
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
    ...
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            ...
            <action name="attributes">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">attributes</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Update attributes</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="catalog/product_action_attribute/edit"/>
                    </item>
               </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction>
     </listingToolbar>
     ...
 </listing>
```

The action path `catalog/product_action_attribute/edit` in this configuration points to layout handle
`Magento_Catalog::view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_product_action_attribute_edit.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        ...
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Action\Attribute" name="attribute" template="catalog/product/edit/action/attribute.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

In this file you'll find the information you're looking for:

- Block class: Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Action\Attribute
- Template file: catalog/product/edit/action/attribute.phtml

**Edit 1:**

@Creativity Group: In that case you should have a look into the extension you use for this functionality.

Here you can see an example in Magento_Customer module where a custom "renderer" is defined for massaction flyout:
`Magento_Customer::view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    ...
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        ...
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            ...
            <action name="assign_to_group">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">assign_to_group</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Assign a Customer Group</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <argument name="actions" xsi:type="configurableObject">
                    <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\MassAction\Group\Options</argument>
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="urlPath" xsi:type="string">customer/index/massAssignGroup</item>
                        <item name="paramName" xsi:type="string">group</item>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Assign a Customer Group</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure to assign selected customers to new group?</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </argument>
            </action>
            ...
        </massaction>
    </listingToolbar>
    ...
</listing>
```

Hope that helps you to find a solution!

**Edit 2:**

Here (`Magento_Customer::view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml`) is an example how to privide your own ui component. Or how to extend existing ui component functionality. Maybe this help you to figure out the solution for your requirements...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    ...
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        ...
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <action name="delete">
                ...
            </action>
            ...
        </massaction>
        ...
    </listingToolbar>
    ...
</listing>
```

See here how Magento extends in this example the functionality of massaction: `Magento_Ui::view/base/web/js/grid/tree-massaction.js`. 
And see this file `Magento_Ui::view/base/web/js/grid/massaction.js` in order to see how the default functionality works:

```
/**
 * Creates action callback based on its' data. If action doesn't spicify
 * a callback function than the default one will be used.
 *
 * @private
 * @param {Object} action - Actions' object.
 * @param {Object} selections - Selections data.
 * @returns {Function} Callback function.
 */
_getCallback: function (action, selections) {
    var callback = action.callback,
        args     = [action, selections];

    if (utils.isObject(callback)) {
        args.unshift(callback.target);

        callback = registry.async(callback.provider);
    } else if (typeof callback != 'function') {
        callback = this.defaultCallback.bind(this);
    }

    return function () {
        callback.apply(null, args);
    };
},

/**
 * Default action callback. Sends selections data
 * via POST request.
 *
 * @param {Object} action - Action data.
 * @param {Object} data - Selections data.
 */
defaultCallback: function (action, data) {
    var itemsType = data.excludeMode ? 'excluded' : 'selected',
        selections = {};

    selections[itemsType] = data[itemsType];

    if (!selections[itemsType].length) {
        selections[itemsType] = false;
    }

    _.extend(selections, data.params || {});

    utils.submit({
        url: action.url,
        data: selections
    });
},
```

According to this information you should figure out your way.

Hope this was helpful!

Comment: I want to do as the examples of the images I added to the top ie how to create the action and the text area to enter the value and save it in the database
You can watch the pictures
Thanks

Comment: I have already managed to modify the value with this code but I am stuck in how I can add an input text to enter the new value , for example enter 20 and press apply, how to add input text and

Comment: @CreativityGroup: see "Edit 2" - hope it's helpful